# Convenient factorisation of position basis of the Hilbert space of lattice-periodic system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, tensor-calculus

I am dealing with a one-dimensional system that has a discrete translational symmetry, i.e. the Hamiltonian has the form
$$
\hat H= \frac{\hat p^2}{2m}+V(x)
$$
where $V(x+a)=V(x)$ and $\hat H$ is an operator acting on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_T$.

Expressing the identity operator in the position basis one has:
$$
\hat {1}_{\mathcal{H}_T}=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \big|x\big>\big<x\big| dx \tag{1}
$$

Now, an equivalent way to express Eq. (1) is
$$
{1}_{\mathcal{H}_T}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \int_{0}^a \big|n\cdot a+y\big>\big<n\cdot a+y\big| dy \tag{2}
$$

Intuitively, I would expect to be possible to express the bra/ket appearing in the identity operator (2) as:

$$\big|n\cdot a+y\big>_{\mathcal{H}_T}=\big|n\cdot a\big>_{\mathcal{H}_d}\otimes \big|y\big>_{\mathcal{H}_c}\tag{3}$$
so that the total Hilbert space can be obtained as
$\mathcal{H}_T=\mathcal{H}_d\otimes \mathcal{H}_c$, i.e. as
a tensor product of an Hilbert space having discrete states ($\big|n\cdot a\big>\in\mathcal{H}_d$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$) and an Hilbert space in which the position operator has bounded eigenvalues, ($\big|y\big>\in\mathcal{H}_c$ with $y\in [0,a)$)

In formulas, I am asking if it is possible to factorise the operator (2) as follows
$$
{1}_{\mathcal{H}_T}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \int_{0}^a \big|n\cdot a+y\big>\big<n\cdot a+y\big| dy  \stackrel{?}{=}\hat{1}_{\mathcal{H}_d}\otimes \hat{1}_{\mathcal{H}_c}
\tag{4}
$$
where
$$
\hat{1}_{\mathcal{H}_c} =\int_{0}^a \big|y\big>\big<y\big| dy \tag{5} 
$$
and
$$
\hat{1}_{\mathcal{H}_d}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \big|n\cdot a\big>\big<n\cdot a\big| \tag{6} 
$$

From an intuitive point of view, I would expect the answer "yes", but I am looking for a rigorous proof (or disproof) of this. Reference to textbooks would be very appreciated.